# Using SELECTEDVALUE in DAX not working correctly

Tags: powerbi, dax, selectedvalue

I have written a DAX code which worked perfectly fine, however, I wanted to add another clause within which says that if the row is for a branch type that equals to IN STORE, it should also do the same SUMX over the summarized table, but as you can see from the screenshot of the current output its returning the incorrect result.

```
totalAverageBaysFinalVersion =
VAR onlyCampaignFiltered =
    ISFILTERED ( 'Campaign Overview'[campaign] )
        && NOT CALCULATE (
            ISCROSSFILTERED ( 'range_plans' ),
            REMOVEFILTERS ( 'Campaign Overview'[campaign] )
        )
            || ISFILTERED ( 'Calendar'[weekNumWeekCommence] )
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Campaign Overview'[branch_type] ) = "IN STORE", --Additional Code
            SUMX (
                SUMMARIZE (
                    range_plans,
                    range_plans[branch],
                    range_plans[range_name],
                    range_plans[number_bays]
                ),
                range_plans[number_bays]
            ),
        IF (
            onlyCampaignFiltered,
            SUMX (
                SUMMARIZE (
                    range_plans,
                    range_plans[branch],
                    range_plans[range_name],
                    range_plans[number_bays]
                ),
                range_plans[number_bays]
            ),
            [Total Avg Bays Campaign Overview]
        )
    )
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Expected Output:**

```
Campaign                               Branch Type             Avg.Bays
2023/07/19 - 2023/08/15 Summer 2         IN STORE              7,806.43
2023/07/19 - 2023/08/15 Summer 2          ONLINE                  0
```

How would I go about checking whether the row is `IN STORE` and making sure it returns the correct value?

Comment: Could you duplicate the measure (for testing) and replace the `RETURN` with: `RETURN
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Campaign Overview'[branch_type] ) = "IN STORE", "INSTORE",
        onlyCampaignFiltered, "onlyCampaignFiltered",
        "TOT AVG BAYS"
    )` and let us know what results you get?

Comment: for the first row it returned `INSTORE` and the second row returned `TOT AVG BAYS`

Comment: So that shows the `SELECTEDVALUE` is indeed working. In your snip, where is the bottom left card coming from? ("totalRangePlanBays')

Comment: the `totalrangeplanbays` is basically the `SUMX(SUMMARIZE...`, I just put it in a card visual to make sure it was the correct number being shown

Comment: If you select the first row of the table, does the `totalrangeplanbays` card change to `6,597.23` ?

Comment: Yes, it changed to `6,597.23` when I select the first row

Comment: So it's working correctly. If the number isn't correct or as expected, then you need to double down on the `totalRangePlanBays` (SUMX...) calculation and understand how/why that row affects it. Can't offer more help here without seeing your data model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255949/discussion-between-jcoke-and-sam-nseir).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on from the comments and chat - the row context is affecting the results you are expecting. See if this works where you `REMOVEFILTERS` for one of the columns in the table for when "IN STORE"...

```
totalAverageBaysFinalVersion =
  VAR onlyCampaignFiltered =
    ISFILTERED ( 'Campaign Overview'[campaign] )
    && NOT CALCULATE ( ISCROSSFILTERED ( 'range_plans' ), REMOVEFILTERS ( 'Campaign Overview'[campaign] )  )
    || ISFILTERED ( 'Calendar'[weekNumWeekCommence] )

  RETURN SWITCH( TRUE(),
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Campaign Overview'[branch_type] ) = "IN STORE", [totalRangePlanBays]( REMOVEFILTERS ( 'Campaign Overview'[branch] ) ),
    onlyCampaignFiltered, [totalRangePlanBays],
    [Total Avg Bays Campaign Overview]
  )
```