# Incorrect total showing in table row but correct value in card visual and grand total

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a DAX code which was having issues and got solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77486605/using-selectedvalue-in-dax-not-working-correctly?noredirect=1#comment136605540_77486605).

```
totalAverageBaysFinalVersion = 
VAR onlyCampaignFiltered =
    (
        ISFILTERED ( 'Campaign Overview'[campaign] )
            && NOT CALCULATE (
                ISCROSSFILTERED ( 'range_plans' ),
                REMOVEFILTERS ( 'Campaign Overview'[campaign] )
            )
    )
        || ISFILTERED ( 'Calendar'[weekNumWeekCommence] )
RETURN
 SWITCH (
    TRUE(),
    SELECTEDVALUE('Campaign Overview'[branch_type]) = "IN STORE", --Here
        [totalRangePlanBays], --Here
 SELECTEDVALUE('Campaign Overview'[ranged_flag_in_words]) = "RANGED",
    [totalRangePlanBays],
        onlyCampaignFiltered,
      [totalRangePlanBays],
        [Total Avg Bays Campaign Overview]
    )
```

However, what I noticed is that when filtering on a range group it no longer shows the correct row value which should be `114.49`.

[image]

But the weird thing is when I remove the code marked with the comment `here` in the code above, it suddenly works again.

Would there be a reason why when adding the code that checks whether the branch type is `IN STORE` makes it not show the correct total on the row but correct in the grand total of the table, and when removed, it works?

[image]

Comment: When you filter `range_group` then `onlyCampaignFiltered` is no longer true, as so it will use `[Total Avg Bays Campaign Overview]` instead of `[totalRangePlanBays]`. And for some reason, you wanted to always use `[totalRangePlanBays]` for when "IN STORE".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
totalAverageBaysFinalVersion = 
  VAR onlyCampaignFiltered =
    (
      ISFILTERED ( 'Campaign Overview'[campaign] )
      && NOT CALCULATE (
          ISCROSSFILTERED ( 'range_plans' ),
          REMOVEFILTERS ( 'Campaign Overview'[campaign], 'Campaign Overview'[branch_type] )
        )
    )
    || ISFILTERED ( 'Calendar'[weekNumWeekCommence] )

RETURN
  SWITCH ( TRUE(),
    SELECTEDVALUE('Campaign Overview'[branch_type]) = "ONLINE", [Total Avg Bays Campaign Overview], // never use totalRangePlanBays which is only for IN STORE
    SELECTEDVALUE('Campaign Overview'[ranged_flag_in_words]) = "RANGED", [totalRangePlanBays],
    onlyCampaignFiltered, [totalRangePlanBays],
    [Total Avg Bays Campaign Overview]
  )
```

What's changed:

- Added `'Campaign Overview'[branch_type]` in the `REMOVEFILTERS` for `onlyCampaignFiltered`. Why? Since you have this column in the table, it is considered a filter in terms of row context.
- Added `ONLINE` branch_type case in the SWITCH. From my understanding, `range_plans` is only for "IN STORE"?

Observations:

- The relationship between `Campaign Overview` table and `range_plans` table seems incorrect. Shouldn't there be a join on `branch_id`?

Comment: That did the trick, thanks a lot - Also the relationship is made that way because of the underlying data source, some `branch_id` are not present in the Campaign Overview table so in order to find it, it has to be linked via the dates to find the associated campaign to the range